# Need to understand one usage of pthread_mutex_lock() and pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_signal()

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded, posix, embedded-linux

I need to understand one usage of `pthread_mutex_lock()` and `pthread_cond_wait()` and `pthread_cond_signal()`.

I have seen a piece of code where a function, say for example, `CallANumber()` is invoked from `main()` and inside this `CallANumber()` function `pthread_mutex_lock()` is used along with `pthread_cond_wait()` and then release by `pthread_mutex_unlock()` and there is another function, say for example, `WaitForResponse()`, inside this function `pthread_mutex_lock()` along with `pthread_cond_signal()` has been called and released by `pthread_mutex_unlock()`.

But I have not found any `pthread_create()` call inside the source base.

Is it possible to call `Pthread_mutex_lock/unlock()` and `pthread_cond_wait/signal()` APIs without a `pthread_create()` function getting never been called ?

Comment: It mostly always is better to quote code, then to (try to) describe in prose.

Comment: if there's no other thread to signal the condition, the code would hang at `pthread_cond_wait()` . Though, the code could create a thread via some library, instead of directly calling `pthread_create()`

Comment: @nos: It's very possible that, in the degenerate case where there's no other thread, the predicate is always true and thus `pthread_cond_wait` doesn't get called in the idiomatic loop. For example, `while (wanted_resource_is_used_by_another_thread) pthread_cond_wait(&cnd, &mtx);`

Comment: @R.. Thanks for reply but can you please elaborate this statement of yours - "in the degenerate case" - I am unable to understand what degenerate case refers or means. Also this statement - "the predicate is always true" - what predicate refers here ?

Comment: @linard_in: The general pattern for using a condition variable is to wait until some predicate (e.g. "is nonempty" or "is nonfull") is true on the data protected by the mutex. By "degenerate" I just meant the case where there's only one thread and thus no others to contend with. Assuming a predicate that doesn't inherently depend on the presence of other threads, it should always be true in the single-thread case.

Comment: @R.. I really appreciate your help in helping me to clear the doubt on degenerate case. And any way the thing is like what nos also mentioned that it is a library which is creating the thread. The same has been resonated in Florian Weimer's statement. I thank all of you guys for clearing this doubt.

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons for using these functions in programs which are not multi-threaded:

- The functions are called from generic code, perhaps in a library, and this library needs to perform synchronization in case the process is multi-threaded (which the library authors do not know).  Without synchronization, the library might not work as expected in a multi-threaded program.
- The synchronization happens across processes instead of threads, using [process-shared mutexes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html) and [process-shared condition variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_condattr_getpshared.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I am unable to understand one point and that is if the library is loaded into the address range of the process , creates the thread and then gets de-referenced from the process address space. In this situation what will be the picture ?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. Would you please elaborate? If the library itself creates threads, then there should be an (indirect) call to `pthread_create`, so I don't see this how this would be an example of a library using mutexes without being multithreaded itself.

Comment: I thank all of you guys for your valuable insights which cleared my doubt.